# gradle: Skipping task ': as it has no source files. and does not generate zip file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 1.4 version. I have the following tasks. 'createWar' works fine and generates me the required 'war file.
But 'createServerPackage' does not generate me 'zip' file.
The below is my build.gradle file. Can someone help me with this?

```
task createWar(type: War, dependsOn: syncConfiguration){
}
task createServerPackage(type: Zip) {
    description = "Creates the full server.zip package for distribution."
    dependsOn createWar

    String filesDirectory = 'upgradeFiles'

    from("${rootDir.absolutePath}/server/build/libs/adapter.war") {
        into(filesDirectory)
    }

    archiveName 'server.zip'
    destinationDir file(buildDir)
}
```

The below is the snippet from compiling gradle.

```
 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':createWar'
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :createWar UP-TO-DATE
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :createServerPackage
 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':createServerPackage'
 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':createServerPackage' as it has no source files.
 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':createServerPackage'
 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :createServerPackage UP-TO-DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to construct the `war` path by yourself. Here's how it should be done:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

task createWar(type: War)

task createServerPackage(type: Zip) {
    description = "Creates the full server.zip package for distribution."
    dependsOn createWar

    String filesDirectory = 'upgradeFiles'

    from(createWar.outputs) {
        into(filesDirectory)
    }

    archiveName 'server.zip'
    destinationDir file(buildDir)
}
```

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/31815265).

Comment: Awesome! This works. I still need some clarification. - I changed     'task createWar(type: War, dependsOn: syncConfiguration){
}'  to     'task createWar(type: War, dependsOn: syncConfiguration).    This seems to do the trick and my package creation was successful. But, could you help me understand why?